# node.js websocket.io example not working?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm new to node.js and working my way through examples of the 'smashing node.js' book.
In the websockets chapter I'm struggling to get this example to work. Forgive me it's a really simple error! I'm not sure the `ws.onopen` event handler is working?

Code is below: (firstly `server.js` file):

```
var express = require('express') , wsio = require('websocket.io');

var app = express.createServer().listen(3000);

var ws = wsio.attach(app);

app.use(express.static('public'));

ws.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log(' \033[96mgot:\033[39m ' + msg);
        socket.send('pong');
    });
});
```

Secondly the script contents of the `./public/index.html` file:

```
var lastMessage;

window.onload = function () {
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost');

    ws.onopen = function () {
        ping();
    }
    ws.onmessage = function(ev) {
        console.log(' got: ' + ev.data);
        document.getElementById('latency').innerHTML = new Date - lastMessage;
        ping();
    }

    function ping() {
        lastMessage =+ new Date;
        ws.send('ping');
        document.getElementById('latency').innerHTML = 'test';
    };
};
```

I have installed the node modules using a `package.json` file.

Comment: Could it be the fact that you are binding to an express server on port 3000, but from the client side, you are defaulting the port to 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *index.html*, you need to connect to port *3000* i.e. `var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');`.

Comment: thanks for the reply - you're right, and I used a more up-to-date version of websocket.io and the example at the link below: https://github.com/LearnBoost/websocket.io/blob/master/examples/echo/server.js. thank you!